# how to call the function to display the data in objective-c

Tags: ios

I am creating the app for kids.I am new to this field.

The below code is for speech:

```
-(void)textToSpeechAction:(NSMutableArray *)imageStoreArray :(int)counter :(UIImageView *)imageChangeImageView :(UIImageView *)spekerOrMic :(BOOL)isMicPresent
{
    spekerOrMic.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"speaker.png"];
    NSArray *items = [[imageStoreArray objectAtIndex:counter] componentsSeparatedByString:@"."];
    NSString *speechString;
    if(_isWritePresent)
    {
        NSArray *viewToRemove = [spekerOrMic subviews];
        for (UIImageView *v in viewToRemove) {
            [v removeFromSuperview];
        }
        spekerOrMic.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@""];
        spekerOrMic.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:41/255.0 green:52/255.0 blue:44/255.0 alpha:1.0];
        NSString *tempString = [items objectAtIndex:0];
        NSArray *tempArray = [tempString componentsSeparatedByString:@" "];
        speechString = [tempArray objectAtIndex:1];
    }
    else
    {
        speechString = [items objectAtIndex:0];
    }

    AVSpeechSynthesizer *synthesizer = [[AVSpeechSynthesizer alloc]init];

    AVSpeechUtterance *utterance = [AVSpeechUtterance speechUtteranceWithString:speechString];
    [utterance setRate:0.2f];
    utterance.voice = [AVSpeechSynthesisVoice voiceWithLanguage:@"en-US"];
    [synthesizer speakUtterance:utterance];

    imageChangeImageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:[imageStoreArray objectAtIndex:counter]];

    if(isMicPresent)
    {
        [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:3.0 target:self selector:@selector(micAction:) userInfo:spekerOrMic repeats:NO];
    }
}

-(void)micAction:(NSTimer *)timer
{
    NSLog(@"mic action");
    UIImageView *micOrSpeaker = timer.userInfo ;
    micOrSpeaker.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"mic.png"];
    // Set the audio file
    NSArray *pathComponents = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                               [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) lastObject],
                               @"MyAudioMemo.m4a",
                               nil];
    NSURL *outputFileURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPathComponents:pathComponents];

    // Setup audio session
    AVAudioSession *session = [AVAudioSession sharedInstance];
    [session setCategory:AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayAndRecord error:nil];

    // Define the recorder setting
    NSMutableDictionary *recordSetting = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];

    [recordSetting setValue:[NSNumber numberWithInt:kAudioFormatMPEG4AAC] forKey:AVFormatIDKey];
    [recordSetting setValue:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:44100.0] forKey:AVSampleRateKey];
    [recordSetting setValue:[NSNumber numberWithInt: 2] forKey:AVNumberOfChannelsKey];

    // Initiate and prepare the recorder
    recorder = [[AVAudioRecorder alloc] initWithURL:outputFileURL settings:recordSetting error:NULL];
    recorder.delegate = self;
    recorder.meteringEnabled = YES;
    [recorder prepareToRecord];

    [recorder record];

    [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1.0 target:self selector:@selector(recordStopAction:) userInfo:micOrSpeaker repeats:NO];
}

-(void)recordStopAction:(NSTimer *)timer
{
    NSLog(@"stop");
    [recorder stop];
    UIImageView *micOrSpeaker = timer.userInfo;
    micOrSpeaker.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@""];

    _isRecordComplete = YES;

    AVAudioSession *audioSession = [AVAudioSession sharedInstance];
    [audioSession setActive:NO error:nil];
}

-(void)recordPlayAction
{
    if (!recorder.recording){
        _player = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:recorder.url error:nil];
        [_player setDelegate:self];
        [_player play];
    }
}
```

alphabet phonics code:

```
    NSMutableArray *arrForA = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"apple.png", @"ant.png", nil];
    NSMutableArray *arrForB = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"bee.png", @"bear.png", nil];


    dictAlpha = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] initWithObjectsAndKeys: arrForA, @"a.png", arrForB,@"b.png", nil];





    NSLog(@"%@",dictAlpha); // 1



    commonFunctionObject = [[SpeechCommonFunctions alloc]init];
    commonFunctionObject.isRecordComplete = NO;
    counter = 0;
    isMicPresent = YES;
    _confirmationPopupView.hidden = true;
    [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:2.0 target:self selector:@selector(repeatActionFire) userInfo:nil repeats:NO];

}

-(void)repeatActionFire
{


    keys=[dictAlpha allKeys];

    if(counter>=keys.count)
    {
        NSLog(@"finished");
        [_alphabetsShowImageView removeFromSuperview];
        [_speakerOrMicImageView removeFromSuperview];
        [_images removeFromSuperview];
        UIImageView *congratzView = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:self.view.frame];
        congratzView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"congratulation.png"];
        [self.view addSubview:congratzView];

    }
    else{


        [commonFunctionObject textToSpeechAction:keys :counter :_alphabetsShowImageView:_speakerOrMicImageView :isMicPresent];
        [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:10.0 target:self selector:@selector(ActionToCkeckRecordCompletion) userInfo:nil repeats:NO];

           }
}

-(void)pik{
      arrVal = [dictAlpha objectForKey:keys[i]];


      if(j<arrVal.count){

            [commonFunctionObject textToSpeechAction:arrVal :j :_images :_speakerOrMicImageView :isMicPresent];
            [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:10.0 target:self selector:@selector(ActionToCkeckRecordCompletion1) userInfo:nil repeats:NO];


      }
    else
    {
       // [arrVal removeAllObjects];
        [_images removeFromSuperview];
        counter+=1;
               [self repeatActionFire];
    }

}
-(void)ActionToCkeckRecordCompletion1
{
    if(commonFunctionObject.isRecordComplete)
    {
        _confirmationPopupView.hidden = false;
    }
    [self pik];


}


-(void)ActionToCkeckRecordCompletion
{
    if(commonFunctionObject.isRecordComplete)
    {
        _confirmationPopupView.hidden = false;
    }
    [self pik];

}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

/*
 #pragma mark - Navigation

 // In a storyboard-based application, you will often want to do a little preparation before navigation
 - (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {
 // Get the new view controller using [segue destinationViewController].
 // Pass the selected object to the new view controller.
 }
 */

- (IBAction)playButtonAction:(id)sender
{
    [commonFunctionObject recordPlayAction];
}

- (IBAction)nextButtonAction:(id)sender
{
    j+=1;
    [self pik];

    _confirmationPopupView.hidden = true;
    commonFunctionObject.isRecordComplete = NO;
    if(commonFunctionObject.player.playing){[commonFunctionObject.player stop];}
    [self repeatActionFire];
}

- (IBAction)retryButtonAction:(id)sender
{


    _confirmationPopupView.hidden = true;
    commonFunctionObject.isRecordComplete = NO;
    if(commonFunctionObject.player.playing){[commonFunctionObject.player stop];}
    [self repeatActionFire];
}
```

In alphabet phonics code ,i need to modify the code.
According the code my output is getting as :
first it display the a.png image then apple image then ant image then b.png image but bat image is not displaying .how to do?

Comment: where are you setting value for i? I saw you are setting for j, but for i I could not catch it. Hopefully If it is not set then there would be the issue

Comment: i have not set.so where should i set

Comment: at what place i need to set the i value

Comment: It depends on, how you want it to implement.
The logic is you need to fetch from the dictionary based on keys, you are putting all keys in array. And then retrieving the first index, so you can get the object array that are storeed in first key. You need to put your logic to fetch second key and hence the object corresponding to it as well.